How to authenticate to MS Teams in a Cypress script?
I wrote a script to log into the MS Teams web site. Unfortunately I am getting an error see the picture in this part of the code:
        // 1. Visit page with error handling
        cy.log(' Step 1: Visiting Teams');
        cy.visit('https://teams.microsoft.com', {
            timeout: 30000,
            failOnStatusCode: false,
            onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
                cy.log(' Page starting to load');
            },
            onLoad: (win) => {
                cy.log('✅ Page loading');
            }
        });

How can I achieve this kind of authentication? I'm trying to solve it with a token login, but so far without success.


You can't use cy.log() inside a beforeLoad and onLoad event handler. Instead you must use Cypress.log().
See this page of the documentation
cy.visit('https://teams.microsoft.com', {
  onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
    Cypress.log({displayName: 'visit', message: ' Page starting to load'});
  },

